# Cannot solve android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException. Help needed?

Tags: android, exception

after searching i've found that some phones (like the Galaxy s) are affected by a strange bug or whatever that cause this error:

```
                            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
            Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2934)
                at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:643)
                at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:669)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511)
                at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5279)
                at android.webkit.WebView.selectionDone(WebView.java:4470)
                at android.webkit.WebView.clearHelpers(WebView.java:1295)
                at android.webkit.WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(WebView.java:1714)
                at c.a(Unknown Source)
                at c.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
                ... 4 more
            android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2934)
                at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:643)
                at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:669)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511)
                at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5279)
                at android.webkit.WebView.selectionDone(WebView.java:4470)
                at android.webkit.WebView.clearHelpers(WebView.java:1295)
                at android.webkit.WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(WebView.java:1714)
                at c.a(Unknown Source)
                at c.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

And this is the logcat if needed and from here it seems that is problem of the swipe function:

```
            10-27 19:19:20.329 I/InputReader(  166): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
            10-27 19:19:20.329 I/InputDispatcher(  166): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '4096f5c8 ***PACKEGE_NAME***/***PACKEGE_NAME***.Game (server)'
            10-27 19:19:20.749 I/InputReader(  166): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
            10-27 19:19:20.749 I/InputDispatcher(  166): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '4096f5c8 ***PACKEGE_NAME***/***PACKEGE_NAME***.Game (server)'
            10-27 19:19:21.689 I/InputReader(  166): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
            10-27 19:19:21.689 I/InputDispatcher(  166): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '4096f5c8 ***PACKEGE_NAME***/***PACKEGE_NAME***.Game (server)'
            10-27 19:19:21.689 W/webview ( 1125): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
            10-27 19:19:21.989 I/InputReader(  166): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
            10-27 19:19:21.989 I/InputDispatcher(  166): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '4096f5c8 ***PACKEGE_NAME***/***PACKEGE_NAME***.Game (server)'
            10-27 19:19:22.159 I/Ads     ( 1125): Refreshing ad.
            10-27 19:19:22.169 I/webclipboard( 1125): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@4051cb08
            10-27 19:19:22.259 I/Ads     ( 1125): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":15,"u_sd":1.0,"u_w":320,"slotname":"a14e098781b871d","msid":"***PACKEGE_NAME***","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.0.4","isu":"F1B8EEEA64C5716BA996D22689C17557","format":"320x50_mb","net":"wi","app_name":"4.0.4.android.***PACKEGE_NAME***","hl":"pt","u_h":480,"u_so":"p","u_audio":1,"prl":792});</script></head><body></body></html>
            10-27 19:19:22.449 I/InputReader(  166): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1
            10-27 19:19:22.449 I/InputDispatcher(  166): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel '4096f5c8 ***PACKEGE_NAME***/***PACKEGE_NAME***.Game (server)'
            10-27 19:19:22.449 W/webview ( 1125): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
            10-27 19:19:22.599 I/Ads     ( 1125): Received ad url: <"url": "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=15&u_sd=1&u_w=320&slotname=a14e098781b871d&msid=***PACKEGE_NAME***&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.0.4&isu=F1B8EEEA64C5716BA996D22689C17557&format=320x50_mb&net=wi&app_name=4.0.4.android.***PACKEGE_NAME***&hl=pt&u_h=480&u_so=p&u_audio=1&prl=792&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=240&ex=1&client_sdk=1&askip=0", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
            10-27 19:19:22.609 I/InputReader(  166): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 0
            10-27 19:19:22.609 I/InputDispatcher(  166): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0, channel '4096f5c8 ***PACKEGE_NAME***/***PACKEGE_NAME***.Game (server)'
            10-27 19:19:23.339 W/dalvikvm( 1125): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
            10-27 19:19:23.339 E/ACRA    ( 1125): ACRA caught a RuntimeException exception for ***PACKEGE_NAME***. Building report.
            10-27 19:19:23.339 D/ACRA    ( 1125): Retrieve application default SharedPreferences.
            10-27 19:19:23.349 V/webview ( 1125): ZoomScale 3 mPreserveZoom: false
            10-27 19:19:23.489 I/ACRA    ( 1125): READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
            10-27 19:19:23.519 D/ACRA    ( 1125): Retrieving logcat output...
```

The only thing that can cause this error is a Timer that i use in my application in the game Intent, i tried to set up a handler but i saw a lot of crash in my ACRA log.

This is the content of my intent, i hope that someone should help me :)

```
            startB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            startB.setEnabled(false);
                            partiColTempo(tempox);
                        }
                    });

                        }


                 private void displayText(final String text){
                        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            //@Override
                            public void run() {
                                tempo.setText(text);

                                if (text.equals("Finished")){
                                    eseguiSuono();                      
                                    assegnaPunti();     
                                    startB.setEnabled(true);
                                    //elapsed=0;
                                    tempo.setText("Waiting");
                                }
                            }});
                    }

                private void partiColTempo(int tempox) {
                    TIMEOUT=tempox*1000;
                    Log.w("tempo timer", ""+tempox);
                    elapsed=INTERVAL;
                    TimerTask task=new TimerTask(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            elapsed+=INTERVAL;
                            if(elapsed>TIMEOUT){
                                this.cancel();
                                displayText("Finished");

                                return;
                            }
                            //if(some other conditions)
                            //   this.cancel();
                            displayText(getString(R.string.tempo_rim)+" " + (TIMEOUT-elapsed) / 1000);
                        }
                    };
                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, INTERVAL, INTERVAL);
```

Is the problem there? Because i can't find other place when i call asynctask.

Comment: From your logcat post, it would appear that the issue is somewhere within an AsyncTask - Are you using one such and if so, could you please post the code for that too?

Comment: From the logcat, it seems that you invalidate some view outside the main thread, and this is not allowed in Android.

Comment: So it's not a problem of the timer? I've to search an AsyncTask? The only "task" used in my app is that timer.

Comment: It seems that you already use runOnUIThread() from displayText()  -  which is correct.  Please post more of your  stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly doing something with UI (i.e. View-derived objects) from `AsyncTask.doInBackground()`. That's not allowed, only the UI thread can touch UI objects.

If you need to update UI from your background/AsyncTask as it's running, you must call [`publishProgress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) which will cause [`onProgressUpdate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) to run on the UI thread. You can also implement [`onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) which will also run on the UI thread once the background thread has finished.

Comment: so it's not the timer (with relative tempo TextView)? I can't find where it is, is there any method to find it?

Comment: According to your logcat the error is in an obfuscated component, i.e. where it says "at c.a(Unknown Source), at c.doInBackground(Unknown Source)". What other libraries are you using?

Comment: maybe i find the solution, i have an old admob library, i'm tryng with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario generally occurs when `AsyncTask` thread is working in the
 background but in the meanwhile, the UI activity class is destroy. So
 after completion of the `AsyncTask` when we try to perform some UI task,
 the above Exception will thrown.